# Why Subject is not rendering in Angular template?

Tags: angular

I subscribe to observable element in component:

```
public sidenav$: Observable<boolean>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sidenav$.subscribe((e) => console.log(e));
    }
```

I see that `e` variable is changed, but temaplte is not rendering:

```
<div class="sidebar" [class.opened]="sidenav$ | async">
   // I get this only when I drag or click or move in browser
</div>
```

How to fit it?

Comment: Are you missing some code here? `sidenav$` is currently not defined in your example. I would expect to see `cannot read property subscribe of sidenav$`

Comment: No, I get `sidenav$` from service

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the entire component, including the service? There are a few things it could be (late subscriber may be the cause), but cannot tell without seeing the full code.

Comment: I think  @plusheen is right, even if you get sidenav$ from service, something looks wrong. Can you edit your post and put some more details of your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a scenario that the template may not change.
That the sidenav source emits event after `OnInit` but before `AfterViewInit`. So try putting a subscription in `ngAfterViewInit` hook. If subscription shows the value but the template doesn't, it must have something wrong with `sivenav$`